# How to use TLS & HTTP/2 with Envoy Proxy

Tags: ssl, openssl, http2, envoyproxy

I am trying to use envoy in front of my Typescript React App for using gRPC from client to server. This envoy proxy sits inside a Docker container within a Kubernetes Cluster.

My API Gateway Proxy is an NGINX proxy that does rate-limiting, filters, authentication communication with my Auth Service, and so on. I needed to enable **TLS** on both the NGINX Gateway, and the gRPC Server it's proxying for.

Here is what the error log looks like:

```
[api-frontend-proxy] [2021-01-06 17:53:41.897][15][debug][connection] [source/extensions/transport_sockets/tls/ssl_socket.cc:215] [C0] TLS error: 268435703:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER
```

My envoy.yaml looks like the following:

```yaml
static_resources:
  listeners:
    - name: listener_0
      address:
        socket_address:
          address: 0.0.0.0
          port_value: 9090
      filter_chains:
        - filters:
            - name: envoy.http_connection_manager
              typed_config:
                "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.config.filter.network.http_connection_manager.v2.HttpConnectionManager
                codec_type: auto
                stat_prefix: ingress_http
                route_config:
                  name: local_route
                  virtual_hosts:
                    - name: backend
                      domains:
                        - "*"
                      routes:
                        - match:
                            prefix: "/"
                          route:
                            cluster: api-gateway-proxy
                      cors:
                        allow_origin_string_match:
                          - prefix: "*"
                        allow_headers: keep-alive,user-agent,cache-control,content-type,content-transfer-encoding,x-accept-content-transfer-encoding,x-accept-response-streaming,x-user-agent,x-grpc-web,grpc-timeout
                        expose_headers: grpc-status,grpc-message
                http_filters:
                  - name: envoy.router
                    typed_config: {}
          tls_context:
            common_tls_context:
              tls_certificates:
                - certificate_chain:
                    filename: "./etc/ssl/server.crt"
                  private_key:
                    filename: "./etc/ssl/server.key"
#              validation_context:
#                trusted_ca:
#                  filename: "/etc/ca-crt.pem"
            require_client_certificate: false
  clusters:
    - name: api-gateway-proxy
      connect_timeout: 0.25s
      type: strict_dns
      lb_policy: round_robin
      http2_protocol_options: {}
      load_assignment:
        cluster_name: api-gateway-proxy
        endpoints:
          - lb_endpoints:
              - endpoint:
                  address:
                    socket_address:
                      address: api-gateway-proxy
                      port_value: 1449
```

And also, if this helps, my NGINX Config is here too:

```
worker_processes auto;

events {}

http {
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent"';

    map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
        default upgrade;
        ''        close;
    }

    server {
        listen 1449 ssl http2;

        ssl_certificate  ./ssl/server.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key ./ssl/server.key;

        location /com.webapp.grpc-service {
            grpc_pass grpcs://api-grpc-service:9090;

            proxy_buffer_size          512k;
            proxy_buffers              4 256k;
            proxy_busy_buffers_size    512k;
            grpc_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            grpc_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
            grpc_set_header Connection keep-alive;
            grpc_set_header Host $host:$server_port;
            grpc_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            grpc_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks to everyone in advance andI'd really appreciate any comments, help or solutions!

Comment: I understand that this is indeed an error with OpenSSL, but is there a way I can make this work with whatever version I have?

Comment: Good question. I don't know I'm new in Envoy. I am using only 1.19.0 version. And answer I have copied from solution we are using that is crated by our DevOps soicialist. And i still don't understand typed_config section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need add transport_socket section under upstream cluster as:

```yaml
clusters:
    - name: api-gateway-proxy
      connect_timeout: 0.25s
      type: strict_dns
      lb_policy: round_robin
      http2_protocol_options: {}
      load_assignment:
        cluster_name: api-gateway-proxy
        endpoints:
          - lb_endpoints:
              - endpoint:
                  address:
                    socket_address:
                      address: api-gateway-proxy
                      port_value: 1449
      transport_socket:
        name: envoy.transport_sockets.tls
        typed_config:
          "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.transport_sockets.tls.v3.UpstreamTlsContext
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I found away around it in the end. Is this googleapi extension a new thing? Never came across it when I was searching?