# create-react-app: how to use http2 instead of http?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, http, http2

how to use http2 on dev for the 'create-react-app' environment. I can't see anything about that in the README or quick googling. please help me out

Answer (score 1):

Making your React App http2 is nothing to do with react actually. It's all about how the build resources (js, html, css files) are served (communication between server to browser).

#### nginx

If you serve the frontend from nginx then you can enable http2 in nginx.conf file.
https://ubiq.co/tech-blog/how-to-enable-http2-in-nginx/

#### envoy

If you use envoyproxy in the edge, then enable it from it's configuration.
[How to use TLS & HTTP/2 with Envoy Proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65601066/how-to-use-tls-http-2-with-envoy-proxy)

#### Node.js

If you use a simple node.js server then enable it there.
https://nodejs.org/api/http2.html
https://nodejs.org/api/http2.html#server-side-example

Comment: create-react-app and using react-scripts that come with it has everything to do with React actually since that's what most devs use to serve the files locally. so while you are not wrong I think this answer is a bit misleading. and no, it's not possible to do with react-scripts.

Answer (score 1):

You don't and can't change this from your react app, or any frontend app in general.

The server that your frontend app is served from, or sends requests to, would be the place to configure the version of http used. And it'll only work if the frontend app is being run from a browser that supports http2, otherwise the requests won't get upgraded to http2 and version 1 will be used instead.

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible with react-scripts. You would have to either eject the webpack and manually configure it to use http/2 or use a different server like mentioned above. Note that http/2 (or h2) only works over HTTPS so if you want to do this locally you would need to create a Locally-Trusted Certificate either manually or using a package like https://github.com/FiloSottile/mkcert